# Aggregate payload of 3 different calls into 1 file | Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I try to aggregate the payload of three http request call into 1 file. I use the scatter gather for that. One of http requests call is using the output response of one http request and the other is alone. The issue is that I can not combine al three payload into one file. Does anyone have experience with this.

Below I have added the code and picture to make it clear.

This is my desire output in the file;

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://servicenow.com/repo/odata/$metadata#Changes",
  "value": [
    {
       "id": "gggggg-210c-49d7-aa25-ddfdfdfdfd",
      "changenr": "1111111111111111",
      "Description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    {
      "id": "fffffff-210c-49d7-aa25-ddfdfdfdfd",
      "changenr": "1111111111111111",
      "Description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",

    },
    {
      "id": "3k3k3k3-210c-3234-aa25-ddfdfdfdfd",
      "changenr": "1111111111111111",
      "Description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    }
  ],
  "@odata.context": "https://servicenow.com/repo/odata/$metadata#Details", #### USE THE ID of CHANGEs to call DETAILS
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "7005fc43-9c9d-43f5-abc1-656565cbdd63",
      "detailDesc": "No number present",
      "Date": "2022-01-24T18:59:58Z",
      "status": false,
    },
    {
      "id": "7005fc43-9c9d-43f5-abc1-656565cbdd63",
      "detailDesc": "No number present",
      "Date": "2022-01-24T18:59:58Z",
      "status": true,
    }
    ],
  "@odata.context": "https://servicenow.com/repo/odata/$metadata#Problems", ## SECOND CALL in the scatter
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "9001fc4a-8c8d-43f5-abc7-146945cbdd63",
      "problemnr": "problem with tank",
      "briefDescription": "H1",
      "reporterName": "unknow,",

    },
    {
    "id": "9001fc4a-8c8d-43f5-abc7-146945cbdd63",
      "problemnr": "problem with tank",
      "briefDescription": "H1 and h2",
      "reporterName": "unknow,",
    },
    {
     "id": "9001fc4a-8c8d-43f5-abc7-146945cbdd63",
      "problemnr": "problem with tank",
      "briefDescription": "H1 and h2 & H3",
      "reporterName": "unknow,",
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks guys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="servicenow.net" port="443" basePath="servicenow/Details?$filter=id eq #[flowVars.arrayCreate]" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        <http:basic-authentication username="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" preemptive="true"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" protocol="HTTPS" host="lol.servicenow.net" port="443" basePath="/services/changes?$filter=Date gt 2021-12-01T10:00:00Z and Date lt 2021-12-01T11:00:00Z" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        <http:basic-authentication username="xxxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" preemptive="true"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration2" protocol="HTTPS" host="servicenow.net" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        <http:basic-authentication username="xxxxxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" preemptive="true"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File3" writeToDirectory="D:\servicenow" workFileNamePattern="second-of-three-#[function:datestamp:ddMMyyyy-HHmmss].json" autoDelete="true" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File2222" writeToDirectory="D:\servicenow"  autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" outputAppend="true"/>
    <flow name="test-filtersFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
                    <dw:set-variable variableName="arrayCreate"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
(payload.value.id) joinBy " or id eq "]]></dw:set-variable>
                    <dw:set-variable variableName="incPayload"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-variable>
                </dw:transform-message>
                <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload ++ flowVars.incPayload]]></dw:set-payload>
                </dw:transform-message>

            </processor-chain>
            <processor-chain>
                <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration2" path="servicenow/problems" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
                    <dw:set-variable variableName="catPayload"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-variable>
                </dw:transform-message>
            </processor-chain>
        </scatter-gather>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\fileshare-service" outputPattern="second-of-three-#[function:datestamp:ddMMyyyy-HHmmss].json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File2222"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide details of the main issue. Why can not you combine the payloads and how exactly do you want to combine them? Please share example inputs for the 3 and expected outputs.

Comment: @aled, thanks again aled, I have added the desire output. I can not combine them, because after the scatter gather there is no access to the variables otherwise I could append them in transform message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scatter-Gather collects the responses from all the concurrent routes, and aggregates them into a single message. In your case there is only **TWO** concurrent routes because one is sequential routes in which one http request is dependent on the other one. so you will not have three response array from Scatter-Gather. You need to provide what is the desired output you want so that we can help you.

The Structure of the Scatter-Gather will look like below which is array of JAVA .

{
"0": {
"attributes": "....",
"payload": ""
},
"1": {
"attributes": "....",
"payload": ""
}
}

Comment: I have added the output under the desire output. I understand what you mean @Harsha but in the first call that runs sqeuential i want them both output too, so with the one under it will be three as the output I have added.

Comment: So the problem you are facing is, the first http call response you are storing in variable is not seen at the end of Scatter-Gather. But I tried it myself and I can see the stored variable even after at the end of the Scatter-Gather. I am trying in Mule4 I am not sure how it behaves in Mule3.

Comment: yes exactly the issue is that I am using Mule 3, which not show the var content after the scatter section. But it must be possible to append those three calls into one. Thanks for helping.

Comment: See if you can  call First http request before Scatter-Gather and store the response in a variable and see that Variable is available even after Scatter-Gather?

Comment: yes that is possible, the only issue If I would make a lot of calls that will use for each

Comment: I do not think so you will have to make too many calls. It is the same thing even if you put it inside scatter-gather or outside scatter-gather. Since Sactter-Gather will not loop.

Comment: you are right man. I have created new question with the actual case that make things maybe better and clear.

Comment: This solution will not work exactly as mentioned because you are using the example of the aggregation for Mule 4 and the question is for Mule 3, which aggregates differently